# Is there a way to convert a local .gsheet file to .csv or xlsx using python

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to read in a local .gsheet file so I can convert .gsheet to .csv or .xls extensions. I cannot use the google sheets api for this particular project so that is out of the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The Google documentation provides a [Python sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_google_document) of **how to download a Google Document with the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) and simultaneously convert it into the mimeType of your choice:**

```
file_id = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo'
request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                             mimeType='application/pdf')
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

**In your case you just need to modify the code sample by specifying the correct MIMEType:**

`mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`